# curl POST with password with httr in R

Tags: r, curl, post, httr

I'm struggling with how to form my curl POST given this example:

`curl -u user:password -i -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" http://127.0.0.1:8080/leads -d @test.json`

In my R, i have the test.json created, i just cannot figure out how to form the POST using httr
everything i do just throws a different error

```
base <- "http://127.0.0.1:8080/"
endpoint <- "leads"
POST(url = paste(base,endpoint, sep=""),
     accept_json(),
     add_headers("Content-Type" = "application/json"),
     body = testjson,
     encode = "json",
     authenticate(user = "user", password = "password"),
     verbose() )

<- HTTP/1.1 400 BAD REQUEST
```

Comment: nvm, i resolved the issue. it was with my json, not the post request. i'll leave this here as example for someone.

Answer (score 0):

nvm, i resolved the issue. it was syntax error with my json, not the post request. i'll leave this here as example for someone.